# Is length of ethernet header necessarily 14?

Tags: c, networking, ethernet

Code snippet from [here](https://www.winpcap.org/docs/docs_40_2/html/group__wpcap__tut6.html):

```
void packet_handler(u_char *param, const struct pcap_pkthdr *header, const u_char *pkt_data)
{
    ....
    /* retireve the position of the ip header */
    ih = (ip_header *) (pkt_data +
        14); //length of ethernet header
    ....
```

But this image doesn't say it's necessarily **14**:

[image]
<sub>(source: [lewis at www.dcs.gla.ac.uk](http://www.dcs.gla.ac.uk/~lewis/networkpages/m04s03EthernetFrame_files/image002.gif))</sub>

How should I do it properly?

Comment: If you edit the question after it has been answered, the answers will look nonsensical. Please do not do it. Ask another question. Or even better, think about what you want to ask and ask the right question the first time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In 802.3, both the source and destination addresses are 48-bit MAC addresses. 6+6+2=14

Comment: Can you elaborate? Shouldn't it be 7+1+6+6+2=22?

Comment: No, because those 8 bytes occur before the frame, not as part of it.

Comment: OK.But it says 2 **or** 6,so it may be 2+2+2=6 or 6+6+2=14,right?

Comment: Not for 802.3. And Ethernet is 802.3.

Comment: Does it hold for both IPv6 and IPv4?

Comment: TCP/IP is at a higher layer than 802.3.

Comment: Can you also elaborate how is value of `const struct pcap_pkthdr *header` populated?

Comment: Not a clue. But that sounds like it warrants a separate question.

Comment: Sure, here we go:) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2797089/whats-pcap-pkthdr-there-for

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it's 14 in most cases for an end-station scenario.
Except the case when you have an 802.1Q frame, that would throw you off by another 4 bytes.
802.1Q is primarily used for VLAN tagging and QoS on router/router communication.

The preamble and start frame delimiter are mostly used by low level firmware to capture a frame. 
By the time when we (application) have access to an ethernet frame, in general we don't have the preamble nor the start frame delimiter.

From what I can recall the 2 byte length of mac address was part of Ethernet I which never really gained acceptance.  And the Ethernet II/802.3 that is having 6 byte addresses is the real common ethernet that we are using nowadays.

Also want to mention that the padding is 0-46, where 46 came from the minimum 64 bytes constraint on ethernet frame for collision detect (CD) purpose.
46(pad) + 14(dmac,smac,type) + 4(CRC) = 64 bytes

Answer (score 1):

The ethernet header is fixed width however extension protocols such as 802.1q for vlan/qos are common and effectivly extend the L2 header.

Answer (score 0):

The Wikipedia has a good picture of the frame

[WIKI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet)

IPv4 / v6 are layer 3 protocols.