# What's pcap_pkthdr there for?

Tags: c, networking, winpcap

Code snippet from [here](https://www.winpcap.org/docs/docs_40_2/html/group__wpcap__tut6.html):

```
void packet_handler(u_char *param, const struct pcap_pkthdr *header, const u_char *pkt_data) 
{ 
    .... 
    /* retireve the position of the ip header */ 
    ih = (ip_header *) (pkt_data + 
        14); //length of ethernet header 
    ....
```

What's `const struct pcap_pkthdr *header` for([definition](https://www.winpcap.org/docs/docs_40_2/html/structpcap__pkthdr.html)), when do we need it, how is it populated (since there is no such info in the packet itself as below)?

[image]
<sub>(source: [lewis at www.dcs.gla.ac.uk](http://www.dcs.gla.ac.uk/~lewis/networkpages/m04s03EthernetFrame_files/image002.gif))</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you would have kept the comment, it would have been a tad easier. It says:

```
/* Callback function invoked by libpcap for every incoming packet */
```

[Here](http://www.winpcap.org/docs/docs_40_2/html/group__wpcapfunc.html) it says about `typedef void(*) pcap_handler(u_char *user, const struct pcap_pkthdr  *pkt_header, const u_char *pkt_data)` :

> `pkt_header` is the header associated
>   by the capture driver to the packet.
>   It is NOT a protocol header.